# animate along certain path of a layer in swift

Tags: swift, animation, cgpath

[image]I am pretty new to iOS, I am facing a small problem about the CAKeyframeAnimation, I want to animate a view to a certain path of another view layer. it is already successfully animating. However, the position of the animation is not what i expected.

As you can see in my code. I create a UIView(myView) with round bounds. I want another view(square) to follow the orbit of myView's bounds. I already set the myView's centre to the middle of the screen. then I try to get the CGPath of myView and set it to CAKeyframeAnimation's path. However, the square is rotate somewhere else, not on the bounds of myView. Could anyone help me? thanks

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)    
    let square = UIView()
    square.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    let myView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    myView.center = self.view.center
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width/2
    myView.layer.borderWidth = 10
    myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(myView)       
    var orbit = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    orbit.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(myView.layer.bounds, nil)
    orbit.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
    orbit.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    orbit.duration = 5.0
    square.layer.addAnimation(orbit, forKey: "orbit")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frame` "describes the view’s location and size in its superview’s coordinate system," whereas `bounds` "describes the view’s location and size in its own coordinate system."

So if you're building the path from `bounds`, then `square` would have to be a subview of `myView`. If you constructed the path using the `frame` of `myView`, then `square` could be a subview of `view`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I find another solution, instead of create the `CGPath` based on some view already existed, I used

```
let myPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: myView.center, radius: bounds.width/2, startAngle: CGFloat(-(CGFloat(M_PI_2))), endAngle: CGFloat((2.0 * M_PI - M_PI_2)), clockwise: true).CGPath
```

in this way, I can specify the centre point of the `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: You can obviously simplify `startAngle` and `endAngle` to `startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI)`. There's no benefit to rotating that by `M_PI_2`.